# Chrome browser not working as expected (onclick/onsubmit error?)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, event-handling, click

Here is one strange thing. Thanks for ideas.

My Chrome browser does not interact with some web pages as expected. When opening the pages on a different device (such as Browserstack or colleages' computers), everything works fine. There must be a problem with my device, it is obviously not linked to the browser version itself.

**Example 1: click on element does not show reaction**
[When clicking on the small gray dots below the main image here](http://www.cqrt.de/campaign-grun/), Chrome usually performs a caroussel switch. On my device, it does not. Clicks are constantly being ignored, although the automatic caroussel switch works just as on any other device.
Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/KR64m.png

**Example 2: click on button does not show reaction**
[When clicking the button "Weiter" on this page in the lower right section of the page](http://tinyurl.com/umfrage-fhkoeln), my Chrome does not show any reaction. Works as expected on any other device.
Screenshot: i.stack.imgur.com/g8dHN.png

- My Chrome Version: 33.0.1750.146 m *(plugins disabled, surfing in anonymous mode)*
- OS: Win 7 Pro SP1 64 Bit

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE:** 
I found out that my Chrome shows different results to a VisualEvent-check than Browserstack.
Have a look here:

- My chrome (buggy): i.stack.imgur.com/Earrs.png
- Browserstack (working): i.stack.imgur.com/zRRgA.png
- What can I learn from that? There are two more event handlers
- There are no VisualEvent differences for the second example, however.

**UPDATE 2:** On a MS Virtual Machine, everything works as expected:
[My comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22337914/chrome-browser-not-working-as-expected-onclick-onsubmit-error#comment33950016_22338280)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning my device, the issue is related to the fact that my device has a touch screen which Chromium does not know how to handle in the standard configuration. Considered a bug.

> ### nzolghadr@chromium.org
>
> The problem is with "'ontouchstart' in window" expression which the jquery.flexslider library uses. Right now on Windows Chrome returns that as true when you have chrome://flags/#touch-events enabled/automatic. Related issues are: crbug.com/467934, crbug.com/555746, and crbug.com/392584 which based on those it seems that Windows thinks something is touch enabled and Chrome just reflects that.
>
> https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=373991#c13

Answer (score 0):

Hm do you deactivted your Javascript by accident?

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/12654?hl=de

Have u tried a different browser on the same device?

Comment: No, JavaScript is activated.
Works on any other browser on the same device, only Chrome is acting strangely.

Comment: Yes, I did. Same behaviour, even on different Win user accounts. :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, but it was solved by itself the next day. Maybe you just need to do a reboot?

Comment: The point is: I have no idea why this is happening. It it constantly happening. Reboot does not help.Maybe something with the Engine itself, in combination with my system? Are there any others out there who are making the same experience with the two web pages that I mentioned above?

Comment: It must be a problem with your system. I have the very same version of Chrome, and got Win7 Ultimate x64 SP1. My last clue would be to change the Chrome profile, but I really doubt that it would make a difference.

Comment: Interesting: I have tried this on a Virtual Machine on my system, emulating Win 7 Enterprise SP1 and the very same Chrome version. Everything works fine there.

Typical case of specific OS <-> browser problem I guess. *puzzled*

Comment: Tried this with Comodo Dragon v31.1.0.0; same problems. I guess there is an issue with the engine and my specific Win config.